# Why is the area under $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ finite and the area under $\frac1x$ infinite?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If this integral is calculated analytically,

$$\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{x}} dx = 2\sqrt{1}-2\sqrt{0}=2.$$

However, the graph of $\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$, so the area under the  graph should approach infinity.

In contrast, the integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac1{x} dx = \ln1-\ln0 =\infty.$$

Indeed, the graph of $\dfrac1x\to \infty $as $x\to 0$, so the area under the  graph should approach infinity.

My question: The red line represents $\dfrac1{\sqrt{x}}$ and the blue line represents $\dfrac1x$. How is it that the area under the red line is finite and the area under the blue line is infinite?

[image]

Comment: What is the antiderivative of $x^{-1/2}$ ?

Comment: I've written that implicitly in my calculations. $2\sqrt{x}$

Comment: Yes I know. But, so, I do not any problem since the antiderivative does not have any problem at $x=0$. This is not the same at all with $\log(x)$ which is undefined at $x=0$. Don't think only about the area under the curve.

Comment: Added a graph for illustration+edited the question title for clarity

Comment: @Integrator I can't see how that leads to the conclusion that area under 1/x is infinite but area under x^-0.5 is finite.

Comment: As a matter of fact the area from 0 to any positive real number will be infinite for 1/x but not for x^-0.5.

Comment: The $\ln$ function is not defined for $0$.

Comment: But x^-1 and x^-0.5 are both undefined at x=0.

Comment: The area under the red curve is clearly smaller than the area under the blue curve, so it should not necessarily surprise us that one area is infinite while the other is finite. Both regions are unbounded (extend infinitely far out), but the spike on the other is so narrow that its total area remains finite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no contradiction: just because a function goes to $\infty$ at $0$ does not mean its integral near $0$ should be infinite.

If you insist on interpreting the integral as area, here's a way to see that the area under the curve $y = 1/\sqrt{x}$ from $0$ to $1$ is finite. The area under the curve $y = 1/\sqrt{x}$ from $0$ to $1$ is the area of the region bounded by the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis, the line $x=1$, and $y = 1/\sqrt{x}$. But if we think about integrating in the $y$-direction, then this can also be interpreted as the area of the region bounded by $y=0$, $x = 1/y^2$, $x=0$, and $x=1$. This is just given by the integral
$$
1 + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{y^2}~dy = 1 + 1 = 2.
$$
(The $1$ at the beginning comes from the square from $0$ to $1$. You should draw the region I described to see what I mean.)

Notice how I've computed the area of the same region, but I've managed to avoid any singularities.

In general this is a very common thing in calculus. There are other seemingly unintuitive results, such as a curve of infinite perimeter bounding a finite area (Koch snowflake) or a surface of revolution with infinite surface are bounding a region of finite volume (Gabriel's horn).

Comment: +1 Integrating over the $y$ axis. Beat me to it by seconds.

Comment: +1 Integrating over the y axis. That's a really clever way of looking at it..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an answer and looking at your calculations I suppose you know how to get it:

$$ \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx = 2 \sqrt{a} - 2\sqrt{0} = 2 \sqrt{a} $$

The point here is that although the graph of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ goes to infinity when $x \to 0$, the *area* between the x axis and this graph is perfectly finite. This might be hard to understand, but you can try to imagine it in the following way. Suppose you take a number $\epsilon > 0$ and now you calculate the area between the x axis, the graph of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and the vertical lines $x=\epsilon$ and $x=a$. With the same integral we've already calculated, you obtain that this area is:

$$ \int_{\epsilon}^{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx = 2 \left( \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{\epsilon} \right) $$

And now you should't be troubled by the fact that the graph of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ goes to infinity, because it is perfectly finite in $x = \epsilon$. Now make $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small, that is, take the limit when $\epsilon \to 0$, the area becomes $2 \sqrt{a}$ and you recover the previous result. The key point here is, from an intuitive point of view, that the interval $(0, \epsilon)$ has length $\epsilon$, which tends to zero. Thus, although the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ diverges near $0$, this *zone of divergence* is so small that you get a finite area. Of course, this is only a small intuitive discussion trying to shed light on your question, not a rigorous reasoning.

To understand a little bit more this idea, suppose you take $p>0$ a real number different from 1. Then, you have:

$$ \int_{\epsilon}^{a} \frac{1}{x^{p}} dx = \left[ \frac{x^{-p+1}}{1-p} \right]_{\epsilon}^{a} = \frac{1}{1-p} \left( a^{1-p} - \epsilon^{1-p} \right) $$

As you can easily check, when you take $\epsilon \to 0$ the result converges if $p<1$ and diverges if $p>1$. Then your example with $\frac{1}{x}$ (which also diverges because of the logarithm) is some kind of *limit*: functions like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ or $\frac{1}{x^{3/5}}$ diverge slow enough near 0 to have a finite area, but $\frac{1}{x}$ or $\frac{1}{x^4}$ don't.

Answer (score 1):

By writing both integrals in form of *limit-of-sum* we get
$$\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{x}} dx =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac {\sqrt n}{\sqrt{ k}} }=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac {1}{\sqrt{ nk}} }=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{H_n^{1/2}}{\sqrt{n}}=2 $$
But following Integral when expressed as *limit-of-sum* Diverges!
$$\int_0^1 \frac1{x} dx =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac{n}{k} } =\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac{1}{k} }$$